# Off-by-one error in the vote reversal logic?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, serial-voting

I noticed yesterday what is seemingly an off-by-one error (or something) in the vote reversal scripts. There were 4 posts of mine downvoted in quick succession, and the reversal script kicked in as I expected it would. However, the *first* of the posts retained the downvote:

[image]

I actually also recalled that this is the second time I've seen this happen. I just sort of wrote off the first occurrence as a fluke or coincidental vote timing between 2 users or something, but now I'm not so sure. Again I believe it was the very first post that was not reversed:

[image]

Bug? Or is something else at play?

Comment: May be the one missed is a legit downvote, from some different user, but in same time range ??

Comment: Perhaps that vote wasn't a serial vote.  In any case, if you suspect serial voting that wasn't reversed by the script you should just flag for moderator attention so they can look into it.

Comment: @Habib: That was what I thought the first time, basically, but since it's happened twice now I'm wondering if it may be a bug.

Comment: @Servy: I've already flagged this (for other reasons), but that seems like an inappropriate way to report what I currently suspect is a bug. I don't really have any way of knowing if it's a bug for sure, but the pattern is consistent, so I'd rather report in case it is.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is *just* an extra downvote not in the same series, not a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Martijn has it right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204677/off-by-one-error-in-the-vote-reversal-logic/204683#comment654630_204677): the algorithm reversed only downvotes that were inside its detection window, so this is no off by 1 bug.

The Community Team has taken care of the rest. As usual, [contact a moderator after 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) if the suspicious voting continues or if you see anomalies that haven't been reversed - they'll be able to sanity-check the situation and pass it on if there's a problem that needs our attention.

Comment: Sorry if I seem dense for asking this, but when you say `Let the community team take care of the rest` are you suggesting that the one vote in each case that was not invalidated is something that I should have flagged because it was part of the serial voting incident? Or is it a completely unrelated coincidence and not something I should act on at all?

Comment: See my edit, @eldarerathis. A single downvote isn't usually considered "abuse"; the five you got *after that* would be (and were) though.

Comment: @Shog9: Okay, so the logic is basically that the first vote is considered legitimate on its own merits (i.e. treated as a "single downvote"), even if it is subsequently followed by a series of others in quick succession, from the same user, towards the same recipient? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: In some cases, yes @eldarerathis. This isn't true across the board, and there are certainly behavioral patterns that inspire much more... greedy... voting invalidation. But in a lot of cases, the first vote is arguably legit - it's after that that things start going downhill...

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying that, @Shog9.